# How to display no user found

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am creating a forgot password feature for an application where I simply update the user password (hashed with bcrypt). However I have no idea how to display if a user does not exist with the code I have so far. I know how to log it, and I am familiar with req.flash for success, but I don't know the conditional to set up to req.flash an error if a user does not exist.

Here is my code:

Routes/users:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/forgot', function(req, res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;

    // Validation
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('forgot',{
            errors:errors
        });
    }
    else {
        User.changePassword(username, password);
        req.flash('success_msg', 'Your password has been reset. Please login.');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
        }
});

module.exports = router;
```

User.js:

```
module.exports.changePassword = function(username, newPassword, callback) {
    var query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, function (err, userToChange, callback){
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if (userToChange) {
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
                    bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {
                            userToChange.password = hash;
                            userToChange.save(callback);
                    });
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log('NO USER');
            return req.flash('error_msg', 'User not found');
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried to return boolean variables from my User.changepassword if a user does not exist, and use those booleans to set up a conditional on the routes page but everything I return is undefined. Can you please help me?

Answer (score -1):

You misunderstood asynchronous actions, you are not suppose to write you code synchronously here. If you need to send a error message when the user is not found, you must put that code in the callback of `User.findOne()`.

In you User.js, you should export something like this:

```
module.exports.changePassword  = (req, res)=>{
    //...
    User.findOne(query, (err, user)=>{
        if(err){
            res.send(err.message);
        }else{
            //Do other stuffs as the user is found.
        }
    });
};
```

And in you Routes/users, just do:

```
User.changePassword(req, res);
```

It's not very good, but still can solve your problem, I recommend you have a look at Promise, which is more convenient for asynchronous operations.

Comment: Where would I pass in username and password?

Comment: Change the first line to `module.exports.changePassword  = (username, password, password2, req, res)=>{`

Comment: Another thought, I think you could put all your code in User.js, and just export `module.exports.changePassword  = (req, res)=>{ ... }`, most people would choose this way.

Comment: OK, great I will give it a try after I try the other suggestion. I have quite a bit more code than this that is not shown, so I need to have it in modules

Comment: Always a pleasure.